# Opencart event handler is not working

Tags: php, event-handling, opencart, opencart2.x

I've got a controller `admin\controller\catalog\exchange`. It has got dummy protected method:

```
class ControllerCatalogExchange extends Controller {
    /**
     * Handles category edit event
     * @param $categoryId
     */
    protected function onCategoryUpdate($categoryId) {
        echo '23'; exit;
    }
}
```

I've registered event handler via sql:

```
INSERT INTO oc_event
SET
  code = 'category.edit.exchange',
  `trigger` = 'post.admin.category.edit',
  `action` = 'catalog/exchange/onCategoryUpdate';
```

It seems that handler is not registered ok, because 23 wasn't echoed after category change via admin interface.

How to set action for event handler to call aforementioned controller's method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. Event handler should be public:

```
class ControllerCatalogExchange extends Controller {
    /**
     * Handles category edit event
     * @param $categoryId
     */
    public function onCategoryUpdate($categoryId) {
        echo '23'; exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: @userlond please accept your answer as accepted one so other person will know

Comment: Ok, It will be possible after 19 hours, as stackoverflow informs me now :)